# Click event not triggering when passing function with argument

Tags: javascript, html, dom, events, addeventlistener

Can anybody tell me why this click event won't trigger? The `function` seems to work fine (except printing out to HTML but I'll come back to that).

```js
function longestWordFunc(stringArg) {
  console.log(stringArg)
  var stringSplit = stringArg.split(" ");
  console.log(stringSplit)
  var longestWord = 0;
  
  for(var i = 0; i < stringSplit.length; i++){
    if(stringSplit[i].length > longestWord){

      longestWord = stringSplit[i].length;   
    }
    longestWord = stringSplit[i];
   };
  console.log(longestWord)
  console.log(longestWord.length)
  document.getElementsByClassName("longestWord").innerHTML = longestWord;
  document.getElementsByClassName("longestWordCount").innerHTML = longestWord.length;
};

let searchString = document.querySelector(".searchString").value;
console.log(searchString);
document.querySelector(".generate").addEventListener("click", longestWordFunc(searchString));
```

```html
<input type="text" name="searchString" class="searchString">

<span class="longestWord"></span>
<span class="longestWordCount"></span>

<button class="generate">Generate</button>
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`longestWordFunc(searchString)` returns `undefined`, so this line:

`document.querySelector(".generate").addEventListener("click", longestWordFunc(searchString));`

is getting evaluated as:

`document.querySelector(".generate").addEventListener("click", undefined);`

And you're not setting anything as the click event listener.

I've fixed your snippet to work below:

```js
function longestWordFunc() {
  let stringArg = document.querySelector(".searchString").value;
  console.log(stringArg);
  var stringSplit = stringArg.split(" ");
  console.log(stringSplit);
  var longestWord = 0;
  
  for(var i = 0; i < stringSplit.length; i++){
    if(stringSplit[i].length > longestWord){

      longestWord = stringSplit[i].length;   
    }
    longestWord = stringSplit[i];
   };
  console.log(longestWord);
  console.log(longestWord.length);
  document.getElementsByClassName("longestWord").innerHTML = longestWord;
  document.getElementsByClassName("longestWordCount").innerHTML = longestWord.length;
};

document.querySelector(".generate").addEventListener("click", longestWordFunc);
```

```html
<input type="text" name="searchString" class="searchString">

<span class="longestWord"></span>
<span class="longestWordCount"></span>

<button class="generate">Generate</button>
```

Comment: This seems really clean thanks but I dont quite understand it all sorry. Why is `longestWordFunc(searchString)` undefined? Isn't it being set at let `searchString = document.querySelector(".searchString").value;`. prior to it being used? Also, isn't `document.querySelector(".generate")`. what it is listening to?

Comment: `longestWordFunc` doesn't have a return statement so when you invoke it with any value it returns `undefined`.

Comment: You've been really helpful thank you. Could  I ask, if you have any advice about how to draw the longest word from my loop? I've fixed the code since the above post so I can find the correct word count of the longest word, but I'm struggling to grab the word itself.

Answer (score 2):

You should define `searchString` inside the event listener of `.generate`. Unless, your `searchString` would be `undefined` as the user hasn't entered any string initially.

```js
function longestWordFunc(stringArg) {
  console.log(stringArg)
  var stringSplit = stringArg.split(" ");
  console.log(stringSplit)
  var longestWord = 0;
  
  for(var i = 0; i < stringSplit.length; i++){
    if(stringSplit[i].length > longestWord){

      longestWord = stringSplit[i].length;   
    }
    longestWord = stringSplit[i];
   };
  console.log(longestWord)
  console.log(longestWord.length)
  document.getElementsByClassName("longestWord").innerHTML = longestWord;
  document.getElementsByClassName("longestWordCount").innerHTML = longestWord.length;
};
document.querySelector(".generate").addEventListener("click", () => {
  let searchString = document.querySelector(".searchString").value;
  longestWordFunc(searchString);
});
```

```html
<input type="text" name="searchString" class="searchString">

<span class="longestWord"></span>
<span class="longestWordCount"></span>

<button class="generate">Generate</button>
```

Comment: This makes sense thank you. Is there a prefered way I could deal with the click event or is this sufficient?

Comment: It is sufficient for you. Btw, it is better to get rid of console logs inside the `event listeners`

Comment: Ah great. Yes, I would do that once it's all working sorry. It's okay to use them for testing right?